# Overflow Warning VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting Overflow Warning while running the below fragment of code:

```
For Each Row In Rng.Rows

    For Each cell In Row.Cells

        cell.Activate

        ActiveCell.Select

        If IsNumeric(ActiveCell) Then

            ActiveCell.Value = CInt(ActiveCell.Value)

        End If

        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=1"

        Selection.FormatConditions

        (Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 20

        End With

        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    Next cell

Next Row
```

cell and Row are both declared as Variant.

The code was written by someone else and the warning is not coming my system. The error is coming in few other systems.

Please let me know if there is a bug in the code or any other way to stop getting this message.

Comment: This code is individually assigning conditional format rules to check if a cell equals 1 for every single cell.  While the code isn't technically invalid, it is extremely inefficient.  What's the end goal here? Just to convert decimals to integers and then highlight anything that results in a 1?

Comment: Also, are you sure this line is correct?   (Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

Comment: What do you mean Overflow warning? This is usually a big fat error.

Comment: I can bet about half virtual beer that you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere on the code. Is it true?

Comment: Error only comes on a few systems?  Is it being used on a mix of Excel 2003 and Excel 2007+ (2010, 2013, etc).  My first guess is as @SeanC has answered, but with all this `ActiveCell` and `Select` stuff going on it could be trying to select a row off the bottom of a 2003 sheet (which would work in 2007+).

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs on this line:

```
ActiveCell.Value = CInt(ActiveCell.Value)
```

**`CInt`** can only cope with values between -32,768 to 32,767.
Check your data types [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(VS.84).aspx) to find out which one will fit your requirements better

Comment: Seems like a decent guess -- but given the question I don't see how you could be certain here.

Comment: That was the only line of the code that I could see would cause an overflow error

Comment: In the given code, this is true, but I suspect that @Vityata is correct and there is an On Error Resume Next which renders OP's guess as to the location of the problem suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. Avoid using `Select` statements. It can cause a lot of errors (which is what I suspect is causing yours). Also, you don't need two loops to achieve this

```
For Each cell In rng.cells
    If IsNumeric(cell) Then cell.Value = CLng(cell.Value)
    With cell
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=1"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 20
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
Next cell
```